# Unit tests with new class as parametr

Tags: mocking, xunit, autofixture, nsubstitute

I have problem with mocking some method:

Interface method:

```
bool IsUserAuthorizedToAction(AuthorizationContextData contextData, AuthorizedActionType actionType);
```

How is called:

```
_userInformation.IsUserAuthorizedToAction(new AuthorizationContextData(brandId),
            AuthorizedActionType.DeleteCampaign);
```

And I want to return true or false for tests... But it always return false!

How I mock it:

```
userInformation.IsUserAuthorizedToAction(
            Arg.Is<AuthorizationContextData>(acd => acd == new AuthorizationContextData("validId")),
             Arg.Any<AuthorizedActionType>()).Returns(true);
```

Returns false - not working.

```
            userInformation.IsUserAuthorizedToAction(Arg.Any<AuthorizationContextData>(), Arg.Any<AuthorizedActionType>()).Returns(true);
```

Still not working

Do you have any idea why and how to make it work?

Comment: Does `AuthorizationContextData` override `Equals`?

Comment: No.  public class AuthorizationContextData
    {
        public string BrandId { get; set; }

        public AuthorizationContextData(string brandId)
        {
            BrandId = brandId;
        }
    }

Comment: You're creating a _new_ instance of `AuthorizationContextData`, which by default has reference equality, and compare it against _another_ instance. Can these two objects ever be the _same_ object?

Comment: Arg.Any is the resolution